# A complete newbie installing virtual switch on WinServer 2008 R2 with Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, switch, virtualization

As somewhat of a novice server administrator, I have a question about Hyper-V, WinServer 2008, Virtual Switches and multiple IPs.

I have a dedicated box which I access through RDP (also KVMoverIP available at my request) and  I have 5 IP addresses available. Yesterday I assigned 2 extra IPs to my box as there was only one IP assigned. The base address that I had ended in .58 and I added .59 and .60 which are also available to me. I did this by following some guides on this website and it went quite well.

Now I have in the past already tried to create a functional Virtual Switch using Hyper-V on this server, but I did not succeed. I have only one NIC available (realtek) and I did not manage to stay connected to the server after installing the virtual switch.

I'd like to give this another try as I would like to set up at least one virtual machine running Ubuntu on this server.

How do I go about this in detail?

These are the steps that I figure I should take:

1. Create new virtual network, transforming my NIC into a virtual switch
   -> which settings here do I need to look for very carefully? Will my main IP (.58) still be usable for my RDP access after creating the virtual switch or do I need to keep using the KVMoverIP after I create the virtual switch? In the past I did not manage to keep my RDP connected after creating the switch. Possibly something to do with the 'host' OS and virtual switches?
2. Assign the IPs to the virtual machines
   -> I have not tried this yet but I'm assuming it won't be terribly difficult?
3. Profit?

Obviously I am not knowledgeable in this but I'm very eager to learn more. I have asked my provider to hook me up with a KVM over the weekend so I can work on it then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you missed is something a lot of new Hyper-V admins miss the first time around.  In the properties sheet in your v-switch there is a checkbox labeled 'Allow management OS to share this adapter'.  If you check that box (which you shouldn't have a choice if there is only one NIC card) that should allow you to remote into the hyper-v box, just keep in mind the current session may be lost while it configures the switch (just reconnect in a few seconds).  As for assigning the IPs just set them as static addresses in the OS like normal, or if these need to be separate then just add a second NIC to the VM and assign the address to that.